# "SVD does not converge" error when creating matplotlib subplots and calling np.random.multivariate_normal

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, svd

I had a problem with the following code in Jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import linalg as lg
```

After running this cell

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1,figsize=(15,15))

# joint covariance matrix
R = np.array([[1.,   0.  , 0.,   0. ,  0.  , 0.,   0.  , 0.  , 0. ,  0.95, 0. ,  0.  , 0. ,  0.,
  0.  , 0. ,  0. ,  0.  ],
 [0.   ,1. ,  0.  , 0. ,  0.,   0. ,  0.  , 0.   ,0.,   0.  , 0.75, 0.  , 0. ,  0.,
  0. ,  0.  , 0. ,  0.  ],
 [0.  , 0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.,
  0.  , 0. ,  0. ,  0.  ],
 [0. ,  0.  , 0.  , 1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.,   0.  , 0. ,  0.  , 0.,   0.  , 0.9  ,0.,
  0.,   0.   ,0.   ,0.  ],
 [0. ,  0.,   0.,   0.  , 1.  , 0.,   0.  , 0. ,  0. ,  0.  , 0.  , 0.,   0. ,  0.8,
  0.  , 0. ,  0. ,  0.  ],
 [0.,   0.  , 0.  , 0.,   0.   ,1.  , 0. ,  0.  , 0. ,  0.   ,0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
  0.2,  0.   ,0.   ,0.  ],
 [0.  , 0.,   0.,   0. ,  0.,   0. ,  1.   ,0.  , 0. ,  0.,   0.  , 0.  , 0. ,  0.,
  0.,   0.3,  0. ,  0.  ],
 [0. ,  0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.,   0.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.,   0.   ,0.  , 0.,
  0.  , 0.   ,0.1  ,0.  ],
 [0.   ,0.,   0.,   0. ,  0.  , 0. ,  0.   ,0.  , 1.  , 0.,   0. ,  0. ,  0.,   0.,
  0.,   0. ,  0. ,  0.7 ],
 [0.95, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0. ,  0.   ,1. ,  0. ,  0.  , 0.,   0.,
  0.   ,0.   ,0.   ,0.  ],
 [0.,   0.75 ,0.,   0.,   0.  , 0.,   0.  ,0. ,  0.  , 0. ,  1.  , 0.  , 0. ,  0.,
  0. ,  0.,   0. ,  0.  ],
 [0.  , 0. ,  0.5 , 0. ,  0.,   0.   ,0.  , 0. ,  0.  , 0. ,  0.,   1.   ,0.  , 0.,
  0.   ,0.  , 0.   ,0.  ],
 [0.,   0.   ,0.,   0.9 , 0.  , 0.,   0.  , 0.   ,0. ,  0. ,  0.   ,0.   ,1. ,  0.,
  0. ,  0.,   0. ,  0.  ],
 [0.  , 0. ,  0.  , 0.,   0.8,  0.  , 0.,   0.  , 0. ,  0. ,  0.,   0.  , 0.   ,1.,
  0.   ,0.  , 0.   ,0.  ],
 [0.,   0.   ,0.,   0. ,  0. ,  0.2 , 0.  , 0. ,  0.   ,0. ,  0.,   0.  , 0. ,  0.,
  1. ,  0.,   0. ,  0.  ],
 [0.  , 0. ,  0.  , 0.  , 0. ,  0. ,  0.3  ,0. ,  0.  , 0. ,  0.   ,0.  , 0.  , 0.,
  0.   ,1.  , 0.   ,0.  ],
 [0.,   0.   ,0.,   0. ,  0.  , 0.  , 0.,   0.1 , 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.   ,0.  , 0.,
  0. ,  0.,   1. ,  0.  ],
 [0.  , 0. ,  0.  , 0.  , 0.   ,0. ,  0.  , 0. ,  0.7  ,0. ,  0.  , 0.   ,0. ,  0.,
  0.   ,0.  , 0.   ,1.  ]])

# joint zero-mean
mu = np.zeros(R.shape[0])
N=1000

np.random.multivariate_normal(mu,R,N)
```

I got the error

```
raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge") LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

This error disappeared when

- I delete the 'fig, axes' line.

I don't understand what matplotlib has to do with numpy....

Answer (score 1):

After checking the code I found another way to get rid of the error:

- I deleted the linalg import (I needed it for some other code which I didn't put here in the MWE) and then restarted the Kernel.

First finding the reason for the error to be reprocucable and then solving it took me some time, so I wanted to provide the **solution** here:

Update all packages (I used Anaconda), then eventually unininstall them with pip and install with Anaconda, and restart the notebook. Then I was able to keep the imports and the code exactly as above and didn't get any error anymore.